# react - fetch from other file not working - without error

Tags: reactjs, http, fetch

In react project, inside App component (the main component) I'm calling to fetch function in another file, the request never sent and not returns any error.

App:

```
async handleSearchapp(keywords, country){
 let result = await queryRequest(keywords, country);
 console.log(result);
}
```

file.js:

```
export const queryRequest = async (keywords:string, country:string) => {
    console.log(`inside query request ${config.backendServer}`);
    const url = config.backendServer + `/linking/wikidata?keywords=${keywords}&country=${country}`;  
    console.log(`inside query request ${url}`);
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'get',
        mode: 'cors',
      }).then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
        return response;
      }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
      }).then(json => {
        console.log('<App> <- %c/linking/wikidata%c with search result:', utils.log.link, utils.log.default);
        console.log(json);
        return json;
  }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  })
}
```

I see it does enter to `queryRequest` and print everything properly, the url is correct but I'm still getting undefined in app component.

I've tried to use `axios` package but the requests still no sending.

It is possible to send requests from another file or it must be in the component?
there is a way to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: console.log(`inside query request ${url}`)
is this line printing?

Comment: yes, and the url is correct and working

Comment: can i post a simplified code sample?

Answer (score 0):

in order to use a function in async/await , this function must return a promise;

```
export const queryRequest =  (keywords: string, country: string) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const url =
      config.backendServer +
      `/linking/wikidata?keywords=${keywords}&country=${country}`;
    fetch(url, {
      method: "get",
      mode: "cors"
    })
      .then(response => {
        resolve(response.json());
      })
      .catch(error => {
         reject(error);
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not solving my problem, the fetch doesn't send http request

Answer (score 0):

```
    import axios from 'axios'
    export const queryRequest = async (keywords:string, country:string) => {
    console.log(`inside query request ${config.backendServer}`);
    const url = config.backendServer + `/linking/wikidata?keywords=${keywords}&country=${country}`;  
    console.log(`inside query request ${url}`);
    try{
      return await axios.get(url);
    catch(error){
      return error.message;
    }
```

}

check what you are getting in console.log(result) and let me know